# Write data from View to each row in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I have model like this

```
 public class InvitationMails
{
    [Key]
    public int Individ_Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Почта")]
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LinkStart { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LinkEnd { get; set; }


}
```

I have datepickers where I enter date.
Also I have emails in table, because I write it on other view.

Here is view

```
 <div class="inner-div3">
    <div class="right-welcome-div2">
        <div class="counterdiv3">
            <div style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top: 5px; background: lightgray">
                <b style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">Время жизни ссылки</b>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 25%;">
            <div style="margin-left: 50px; float: left; margin-top: 20px; height: 25%;">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <b>Время начала </b>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Время окончания">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div style="margin-right: 50px; float: right; margin-top: 20px; height: 25%;">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <b>Время окончания </b>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date2" placeholder="Время окончания">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 23%;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First().Link, new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control", placeholder = "Ссылка", @style = "margin-top:35px;",id = "date" })
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <input type="submit" value="Генерировать" style="font-size: 16px" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="left-welcome-div2">
        <div class="counterdiv2">
            <b style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">Список приглашений</b>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 60%; width: 100%; overflow: auto">
            @{int rowNo = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;">
                    <b>@(rowNo += 1)</b>
                    <b style="margin-left: 10px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.To)</b>
                    <a style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;" href='@Url.Action("Edit", "InvitationMails", new {id = item.Individ_Id})'>
                        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")' />
                    </a>
                    <a style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;" href='@Url.Action("Delete", "InvitationMails", new {id = item.Individ_Id})'>
                        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")' />
                    </a>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div style="height: 20%; width: 100%">
            <ul class="btn btn-default" style="width: 150px; list-style-type: none; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 20px">
                <li style="color: white">@Html.ActionLink("Добавить почту", "Create", "InvitationMails", null, new { @style = "color:white" })</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="btn btn-default" style="width: 150px; list-style-type: none; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 230px">
                <li style="color: white">@Html.ActionLink("Отправить", "SendEmail", "InvitationMails", null, new { @style = "color:white" })</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
   $('#date').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
   });
   $('#date2').datepicker({
       format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
   });
   </script>
```

I need to take date from date pickers and enter in all rows in table when I tap this button `<li style="color: white">@Html.ActionLink("Отправить", "SendEmail", "InvitationMails", null, new { @style = "color:white" })</li>`

How I can do this?

Thank's alot for help

**UPDATE**

I write method like this, but it updates table with static data.

How I can transfer data of datepickers to this method?

```
   public static void UpdateLinkStart()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        IEnumerable<InvitationMails> customers = context.InvitationMails
            .Where(c => c.Link == null)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(c => {
                c.Link = "test.com";
                return c;
            });
        foreach (InvitationMails customer in customers)
        {

            context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }



        context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how use the date time picker or are you asking how to post the selected dates back?

Comment: Nope. I make datepicker. It Works

I need to post date to all rows in table that are already here.@Wheels73

Comment: Wrap your view in a form and post it back to your controller.

Comment: you talk about this? `@using (Html.BeginForm())` @Wheels

Comment: Yes....  @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: I do, but this add new row in table, but I need to insert data to already exists records @Wheels73

Comment: So.. you have the datetime picker working ok... you successfully post the model data back to your controller ok... surely the rest is down to your own business logic that acts on that data. Why is it inserting into the database instead of updating!?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: All ok, I solve problem@Wheels73